# CSS Problem with http://www.indianpotterymall.com

Tags: css

I have been racking my head trying to fix http://www.indianpotterymall.com. for some reason the main section has moved to the bottom of the page under everything and I can't get it to pop back up to the top where it should be. The home page is fine but when you go into a category is when it get's all wacked out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that `.maincontent` is a sibling of `#rightcolumn` instead of being its child. Try placing your `.maincontent` `div` *inside* the `#rightcolumn` `div`.

Comment: I figured it out. I had removed an important div and i also moved .maincontent and put it whee it belongs. Thanks for your help.